# How to consult firebase daily and check if the date is the same as the current date and send an email automatically?

Tags: firebase, web-services, google-cloud-firestore, sendmail

My problem is this:

I use Firebase to store images, audios, texts, videos.

And I have a flutter application where the user adds these images, audios, etc.

In this application the user can send these files to someone, for that he needs to choose the date and write the destination email.

When clicking on the "send" button, the email and the date will be saved in the firebase.

The problem is in sending the email.

Basically, I would need to consult firebase every day to check if there is any email to be sent. I would need to consult the date and if the date is the same as the current date, I would receive the email and files and send the email to the person.

After some research, I saw that I could use a cron job and create a web service, but I have a lot of doubts on how to do that. Or are there other solutions?

Thanks to anyone who helps.

> Firebase

**Storage of email, files to send and date**

[image: Storage of email, files to send and date]

**Storage of images**

[image: Storage of images]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or are there other solutions?

Yes, one classical solution in your case is to use a [scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?authuser=0).

You would run this Cloud Function once a day and in this Cloud Function, you would use the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin?authuser=0) to:

1. Query the emails collection based on the date (you may concatenate the day, month and year in one field)
2. Based on the result of this query, loop over the documents, in order to, for each document, get the file to be sent and send an email.

To start with Cloud Functions you should look at the official [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) as well as at the [video series](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/video-series?authuser=0). The official samples are also a must read, in particular, in your case, the sample which shows [how to send a mail](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation).

(Note that, if you are not familiar with Cloud Functions, you will probably have to go through a learning curve that may seem steep at first sight... But as soon as you have tried the first steps you should not hesitate to ask new questions in Stack Overflow with the code you have written and the problem/difficulties you encounter: we will help you with pleasure!)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering. Do I need to pay to create a Cloud Function programmer? Because this is just a job for the school.

Comment: No if your usage is only for a school work: there is a generous free tier and you will hardly reach the limit of this tier, similarly to the Firestore free tier (See https://firebase.google.com/pricing). However, you need to create a billing account with a credit card, in order to be able to deploy, even if no money is withdrawn from your card.

Comment: Another possibility would be to use Node.js 8 which is deprecated but can work without a credit card. This could be an option for a school work that do not need to be used after February 15, 2020, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?authuser=0#set_nodejs_version).